# how to check existence of a command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a configuration script which needs to install few packages only if they are not already present so I tried the following ways which worked but I get the error on my screen that the 'command not found'

I tried :

```
if ! type "$foobar_command_name" > /dev/null; then
  # install foobar here
fi
```

and

```
    function test {
    "$@"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        #install this package
    fi
    return $status
}

test command1
test command2
```

Comment: Don't use function name as `test`. [`test`](http://man.cx/test) is a bash built-in. ( `if [ expression ]; then ....` is exactly same as `if test expression; then ....`).

Comment: `if ! type "$foobar_command_name" > /dev/null 2>&1; then ... fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` as well (not just `stdout`).

For this, you can use the `2>&1` redirect which joins stderr into stdout, which you then redirect to `/dev/null`.

The following should work:

```
if ! type "$foobar_command_name" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # install foobar here
fi
```

Note that instead of doing it this way, you could also do it as:

```
if ! type "$foobar_command_name" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # install foobar here
fi
```

Comment: thank you :) you are right . should redirect even the stderr (y)